How to authorize in python google cloud library with API-token
How to authorize with API-token?
My code
from google.auth.api_key import Credentials
from google.cloud.storage import Client

client = Client('my-project', Credentials('my-token'))
blobs = client.list_blobs('my-bucket')
for blob in blobs:
    print(blob.name)

raises
google.api_core.exceptions.Unauthorized: 401 GET

How to do this correctly?
I can't to authorize with json because it runs in docker container and in production environment I can't mount volume with json, only API-token in envs.

You can't use API keys to authenticate (!) requests to Google Cloud Storage.
Google Cloud Storage requires OAuth to authenticate requests and IAM to authorize "things" (users, groups, service accounts etc.).
The exception to this auth requirement is for public (non-authenticated) objects for which you can't enforce the API key requirement.
Generally you don't want to use API Keys see Google's Authenticate by using API keys for a good explanation of why this is so.
You can authorize apps that run in containers and in production environments because you generally don't mount JSON keys as strings in these environments.
Google discourages the generation of keys.
Please see Application Default Credentials (ADC) for the general approach.
In the following cases, there are more specific solutions. If your production system is:

Google Cloud compute service (Cloud Run, Compute Engine, Kubernetes Engine* etc.), ADC provides a mechanism to automatically obtain credentials from the platform's metadata service.
Kubernetes Engine, there's an alternative and "more difficult to configure but easier to use" mechanism called Workload Identity Federation for GKE
off-GCP but on AWS, Azure etc. you can use Workload Identity Federation


This code will work for you:
import google.auth
import google.auth.transport.requests

creds, _ = google.auth.default(
    scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
)
auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
creds.refresh(auth_req)
# to be used e.g. in python requests:
headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {creds.token}"}

